# Regular Expression for spaces present or not

Tags: java, regex

I tried to make regular expression of a String Declaration where in whole code file spaces can be present in some place before the declaration and in some place declaration starts from left of the line with out any spaces... How can I handle that spaces?

Just like..

1. <---spaces------->String sVariable;  //Spaces present before declaration//
2. String sVariable; //Spaces not present before declaration//

I have tried like -
 strLine.toUpperCase().matches(".*STRING\s.*")  ---but it points 1st declaration. How to declare the regular expression so that it points both..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using<sup>1</sup>

```
strLine.matches("(?i)\\s*STRING")
```

In general, `X*` means `X` *0 or more times*. `(?i)` is the flag to ignore case.

Although you might also want to consider

```
strLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("STRING")
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that if you are going to be using a particular regex repeatedly you should pre-compile it via [`Pattern.compile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) and use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: Using `matches()` in `String` is not a good practice, it compiles the regex every time it executes which is redundant. It is a good practice to use `Pattern.compile()` and then get the `Matcher` object and call `matcher.matches()`

Comment: @JavaTechnical I am aware, I tried to deviate least from what the OP was already doing, but I will make a note of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this to account for spaces before `String` and spaces right after it: `\\s*String\\s+(\\w+)` (it will also capture the variable name.

A test program:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {

   static final Pattern stringDeclaration = Pattern.compile( "\\s*String\\s+(\\w+)" );

   static void match( String s )
   {
       Matcher m = stringDeclaration.matcher( s );
       if( m.find() )
           System.out.println( "Found variable: " + m.group(1) );
       else
           System.out.println( "No match for "  + s );
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      match( "    String s1;" );
      match( "String s2;" );
      match( "    String     s3;" );   
      match( "    String s4   ;" );   
      match( "    String s5;   " );   
   }
}
```

There are also a number of online regular expression testers. I like the one at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.matches()` like thus:

```
if (strLine.matches("\\s*String\\s.*"))
```

The regex for `matches()` must match the *whole* string, so that's why there's a `.*` at the end.

This regex also allows for a non space char, like a tab, after "String"